# Homeomorphism of union of infinitely many topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, zariski-topology

> Let $X = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty X_i$ and $Y=\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty Y_j$
>   such that $X_i$ is homeomorphic to $Y_j$ whenever $i=j$. Then is it
>   true that $X$ is homemorphic to $Y$? If yes, then how do we see this
>   homoemorphism? If not, then what is the problem?

I think the answer to the above question should be yes, but then, in general, $Y$ itself might not be a topological space, since the union of topological spaces need not be a topological space.

**Context:** I have a topological space $X$ with Zariski topology, and I can write is as countable union $X=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty X_i$. Then I can prove that each $X_i$ is homeomorphic to a topological space $Y_i$ with Zariski topology. From this can I conclude that $X$ is homeomorphic to  $\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty Y_j$? If yes, then what exactly is the homeomorphism? How do we define the topology on this union $\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty Y_j$, since we know that union of topological spaces need not be a topological space?

The Zariski topology on $X=\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is defined as the topology in which the closed sets are $V(I) = \{P\in \mathrm{Spec}(A): I\subset P\}$ where $P$ is a prime ideal and $I$ is an ideal of the commutative ring $A$.

Comment: What's the topology on the union?

Comment: @Randall can we define a topology on the union to make sense of the homeomorphism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_i=(-i,0)$ when $i$ is even and $(0,i)$ when $i$ is odd. Let $Y_i=(-i,i)$ for all $i$. Then each $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are clearly homeomorphic (they are translates of each other). But $X=\cup_i X_i=(-\infty,0) \cup (0,\infty)$ and $Y=\cup_i Y_i=(-\infty,\infty)=\mathbb{R}$ and $X_i \not\cong Y_i$ since the latter is connected and the former is not.

The issue is that the topology of the union can have different properties than that of the individual topologies of the pieces making it up. Indeed, the topology of the $X_i$ and $Y_i$ can have nothing to do with the topology of the union. My example was chosen so that there was some way to make sense of the topology of the union but there is no canonical way of doing so generally (insofar as I am aware).

Comment: Thanks! Is there any possibility of this being correct in context of Zariski topology? Is there some special property I should be looking for so that the statement holds?

Comment: It is even harder (at least for me) to write down an explicit example in the case of a general variety even an affine variety as the open sets in the Zariski topology are 'huge'. Either this makes it much harder for the result to be true or makes it much easier, which I cannot decide. But the problem again boils down to how does one define a topology from a union of possibly unrelated topological spaces...

Comment: ...What topology do you define on a space with $X_1=$ sphere, $X_2=$ Mobius strip, $X_3=$ set of 13 points, $X_4=$ emptyest, $X_5=\mathbb{P}^3$, etc.? Even if they are related in some sense, there can be issues. Take examples from Topology or Differential Geometry of local and not global homeomorphisms, e.g. 'X' is locally Euclidean but not globally. If you want an example with a Zariski topology, your best bet may be this exact type of 'picture drawing' so that you can know something works without having to construct all the sets yourself.

Comment: I feel like...maybe we could do something with just $X = \mathbb{P}^2 = U_0\cup U_1\cup U_2$ where $U_i$ is the $i$th affine chart?

Wait...the union doesn't even make sense. The $Y_i$'s aren't assumed to be subsets of some larger topological space $Y$, are they? Or do you just mean the disjoint union of the $Y_i$'s? If you mean the disjoint union, then it's game over with just the example I described above. We certainly don't have that the disjoint union of $U_0, U_1, U_2$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^2$ which is the disjoint union of those sets quotient'd a special equivalence relation.

Comment: I can only imagine the disjoint union is what is actually meant since there is no specification on the $Y_i$'s. Even with the restriction to these being subspaces of a larger space does not improve the situation as with my example or anything involving a local but not global homeomorphism. One would still require even more restriction on the sets. The whole issue really boils down to how does one define a topology on the union. In special cases, the conjecture might hold, but it would greatly depend on the spaces and the topology of the union - which is the point.